# Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n^3\over k^2-2nk+2n^2}$

Tags: limits

> Find the value of $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n^3\over k^2-2nk+2n^2}$$

\begin{align}&\color{white}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n^3\over k^2-2nk+2n^2} \\
&= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n^3\sum_{k=1}^{n} {1\over k^2-2nk+2n^2}\\
&= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n^3\sum_{k=1}^{n} {1\over n^2 + (n-k)^2}\end{align}

It looks there would be some way to split that denominator into somewhat easier form to handle.

Any hint for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n^3\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2+(n-k)^2}\ge n^3\cdot \frac1{n^2+0}=n\to\infty $$

Comment: I think it ought to be $2n^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The last term equals $n$, so the series certainly diverges.

Comment: Actually, all terms exceed $n/2$, but we needn't even care.